# Dagger2 module: how to obtain context to pass to the constructor of a class I want to provide

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

First time using Dagger2.

In my android application I have a MyApplication class that extends Application.
I also have an ImageAssistant class that is a collection of related image-processing methods.
In my MyApplicaiton class I used to instantiate an ImageAssistant for all the activities to use.

Now I am trying to make it work with Dagger2, but I dont know how to pass a context in the module that provides ImageAssistant

This is how my code looked:

```
public class ImageAssistant {

    Context context;

    public ImageAssistant(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    // A bunch of methods...

}

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public ImageAssistant imageAssistant;

    public void onCreate() {

        imageAssistant = new ImageAssistant(this);
    }

}
```

Now, enter Dagger 2, here is what I have

```
public class ImageAssistant {

    Context context;

    @Inject
    public ImageAssistant(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    // A bunch of methods...

}

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Inject
    public ImageAssistant imageAssistant;

    public void onCreate() {


    }

}
```

in package .modules:

```
AppModule.java


@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    ImageAssistant provideImageAssistant() {
        return new ImageAssistant(); // HERE A CONTEXT IS NEEDED. WHERE TO GET IT FROM?
    }

}
```

EDIT: This is how my module looks now, but I still dont know how to tie everything together:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private MyApplication application;

    public AppModule(MyApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return this.application;
    }

    @Provides
    ImageAssistant provideImageAssistant(ImageAssistant imageAssistant) {
        return imageAssistant;
    }

}
```

And this is the AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    ImageAssistant provideImageAssistant();
    Context context();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module should look like this:

```
@Module(injects = {MainActivity.class})
public class AppModule {

    private MyApplication application;

    public AppModule(MyApplication application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    public ImageAssistant provideImageAssistant() {
        return new ImageAssistantImpl(application); // implementation of ImageAssistant
    }

}
```

Usage in `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Inject
ImageAssistant imageAssistant;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedObjectGraph.inject(this);
    imageAssistant.doSomething();
}
```

}

Don't forget to init the `ObjectGraph` in `Application` class. I use `SharedObjectGraph` static class to share `ObjectGraph` created from `AppModule` across the whole app.

Read [building the graph](http://square.github.io/dagger/) section.

Comment: and how do I use the image assistant from an activity?

Comment: You have provided a link to Square's Dagger building the graph, Im using Dagger 2. Is it the same?

Comment: No Dagger2 is forked from Square's Dagger. I use Square's Dagger and above snippets of code are about it. But it should also work in Dagger2, because those are the major things.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final SpendApplication app;

    public ApplicationModule(SpendApplication app) {
        this.app = app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public Context providesContext() {
        return app;
    }

}
```

and:

```
@Module
public class GattManagerModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    GattManager providesGattManager(Context context) {
        return new GattManager(context);
    }
}
```

And declare all places where it's used:

```
@Component(modules = { ApplicationModule.class, GattManagerModule.class, ...})
@Singleton
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(MainScreenActivity activity);
    ...
}
```

In my app application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();

}
```

And in my MainActivity:

```
@Inject
GattManager gattManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but does not work. GattManager (in my case ApiClient) throws a nullpointer exception

Comment: Okay, let me know if there is something wrong in my answer and I will update it. Or feel free to do it yourself if you got enough reputation.